# How to set default + own classes in "excludedClasses" in checkstyle

Tags: java, xml, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle with the following configuration in `checkstyle.xml`

```
<module name="ClassFanOutComplexity">
    <property name="max" value="20"/>
    <property name="excludedClasses" value="MyLogger"/>
</module>
```

I want to exclude `MyLogger` class but with default classes also excluded without writing them to "excludedClasses" property

Comment: @Michael you are referring to `excludedPackages` property, not `excludedClasses` property.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, it is not possible to extend default list, one can only override it.

There is a workaround - you can use `excludeClassesRegexps` property and specify your class name there, e.g.

```
<module name="ClassFanOutComplexity">
    <property name="max" value="20"/>
    <property name="excludeClassesRegexps" value="MyLogger"/>
</module>
```

Comment: I accepted it as an answer, but I will go with just coping all default classes